# Variable substitution not happening in job dsl

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Trying to create new jobs whenever there is a new branch entry in my SVN repo and below is the script.

```
svnCommand = "svn list --xml http://myrepo/svn/repo_name/branches"
def proc = svnCommand.execute()
proc.waitFor()
def xmlOutput = proc.in.text
def lists = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlOutput)
def listOfBranches = lists.list.entry.name

listOfBranches.each(){
  def branchName = it.text()
println "found branch: '${branchName}'"
}

mavenJob('${branchName}'){
  mavenInstallation('M3.3.9')
  logRotator(365, 25, -1, -1)

   scm {
     svn {
       location('http://myrepo/svn/repo_name/branches/${branchName}') {
        credentials('4t4d8ef-p67a-5298-a011-580ghe898a65')
       }
     }
   } 
}
```

Script is able to iterate thru branches and print the branch names,

found branch: 'feature_01'

but I'm facing the issue , while variable substitution while creating the job name and with the svn branch name.

> hudson.model.Failure: ‘$’ is an unsafe character

Jenkins - V.2.32

Job DSL - V.1.57

Any suggestions please.Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about exact problem. However, you should change `mavenJob('${branchName}')` to `mavenJob(branchName)` and `location('http://myrepo/svn/repo_name/branches/${branchName}')` to `location("http://myrepo/svn/repo_name/branches/${branchName}")`

Comment: @Rao : Thanks for looking into it. I went with your suggestion and below is the issue.

**ERROR: (script, line 14) No such property: branchName for class: script**

Comment: That is because, it was not in the scope if you look at your script.

Comment: @Rao : Could you pls let me know what should be done to overcome this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Rao is right: first - you have to change:

```
mavenJob('${branchName}')
```

to:

```
mavenJob(branchName)
```

and:

```
location('http://myrepo/svn/repo_name/branches/${branchName}‌​')
```

to:

```
location("http://myrepo/svn/repo_name/branches/${branchName}‌​")
```

Moreover `def branchName = it.text()` inside iteration limits scope of variable to this iteration only. Try:

```
listOfBranches.each() {
  branchName = it.text()
  println "found branch: '${branchName}'"
}
```

Comment: @gkcour : Yes made a silly mistake, identified and fixed it. Thanks for your time.